# How to create hyperlinks that pre-select data filter category?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, filter, hyperlink

I have a question regarding data filters. Specifically, how to tag data filters in a way that lets me create hyperlinks for those filters, so that when clicked, the link will open the page and pre-select that filter from the portfolio.

I am using WordPress with the Avada theme for this site in question. I have reached out to their support team, but this request falls out of scope with what they will assist.

I have very limited knowledge of JS and PHP, but I'm not opposed to digging in and figuring out how to edit. I just need to know where to start.

Let me give you an example. Take the existing category "Government" on this dev site (see image below).

The Avada filter loads it as: `<a data-filter=".government" href="#">Government</a>`. Is there a way to automatically label the href as the category? So that the html would then read, `<a data-filter=".government" href="#government">Government</a>` so I could create hyperlinks to pre-filter to that Government category?

Please let me know if I can provide any other details on this to gain assistance. I appreciate it!

[Here is a screenshot of the actual site I'm trying to edit, with notes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqOqs.jpg)